# More productive Grooming Sessions

Tags: agile, scrum, requirements

I'm looking for a way to make our Scrum Grooming Sessions more productive. At the moment, it feels like it's taking us a long time to create user stories and acceptance criteria. For a one hour session, we typically end up with 2 - 4 user stories including acceptance criteria. The process to get there feels painful, taking a long time.

Participants include members from Dev + Architecture, QA, BA, Customer, Product Owner (me), Usability.

The problem I see is that we have good discussions, but then the process of wording the stories - and even more so the Acceptance Criteria - takes an awfully long time.

Since we are a distributed team, we have to do this over the phone, screen sharing and a collaborative editing environment. This certainly has an impact on the productivity, since we're not in the same room, but I still feel that our process could be improved.

Some questions:

- How many stories do you typically end up with after a Grooming Session?
- Do you create the Acceptance Criteria as part of the Grooming Session, or outside?
- How do you create User Stories and what process works for you?

Comment: should be on [programmers.se]

Answer (score 2):

**Ask the team!**

Fair, my answer is short so let me explain.  The team has better context of your technology, issues, cultures and product than anyone else here; thus they are the best to answer it.  This is a typical topic you should bring up in a retrospective and in the spirit of continual improvement - Inspect and Adapt.  Keep adapting and trying things until things start getting better.

So in your next retro, bring it up and inspect the problem and admit it is unproductive.  Look at opportunities to adapt and do it.

Some Tips (but not as a Scrum Master)

- Scrum recommends 10% of your capacity spent on grooming
- There is no rule that everyone should do it in a meeting
- Have meetings to manage exceptions or areas where more formal discussion is required
- Try some pair grooming
- Remember a Story is a placeholder for communication, not a contract
- Get the core acceptance criteria,  build the rest in planning sessions and in sprint

> How many stories do you typically end up with after a Grooming Session?

Just enough for the next two sprints with a Just-In-Time attitude

> Do you create the Acceptance Criteria as part of the Grooming Session, or outside?

Both, the critical business acceptance criteria in a formal session with the PO and the functional ones outside of the session as they are identified. Acceptance Criteria should be added the whole time, even in sprint planning and within the sprint.  Avoid treating them as a contract.

> How do you create User Stories and what process works for you?

I normally start with the business focus story that delivers on a business need.  In grooming we break it down to functional stories by using an action/verb or use case model.  These can be written as stories.  In a typical 1 hour session, you can easily brainstorm over 50 requirements at a high level.   As the implementation sprint gets closer, you can break them down into INVEST stories; but report at the functional level.